# config_csync.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, owncloud

I convert [Owncloud  client/Desktop app](https://github.com/owncloud/client) to Qt project using `qmake` command line.

Then , I became able to import this project in Qt IDE .

I added required dependencies to `.pro` file (.i.e: QTNetwork..etc).

I reach a phase where Qt cannot find path to`config_csync.h` , and the error message was :

> /usr/share/ws/client/csync/src/std/c_private.h:26: error:
>   config_csync.h: No such file or directory  #include "config_csync.h"

- Is it something missing in new branches ?
- Which branches contains this file : `config_csync.h` ?

  OR
- Is it an issue of gcc compiler or dependencies ?

Comment: Looks like it generated: https://github.com/owncloud/client/blob/master/csync/config_csync.h.cmake

Comment: yep.. i have this file (`config_csync.h.cmake`), however , how to generate `.h` from `.h.cmake`